# Error: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1433 docker

Tags: sql-server, macos, docker

I am using Docker to install SQL Server on Mac OS. But i have an error `Error: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1433`. I have set memory to 6GB, password is strong enough but it still not works.

Comment: That sound more like an issue with the port, is SQL Server using that port (maybe try `lsof -nP +c 15 | grep LISTEN`) or does your firewall block access to it?

Comment: when I try `lsof -nP +c 15 | grep LISTEN` there is no 1433 port and I also turn off firewall.

Comment: If there is no such port then Sql server is not running or using another port.

Comment: Is it necessary to turn off the firewall?@nhanncv

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue when I've tried to connect Azure Data Studio to the container,

I used the command `lsof -nP +c 15 | grep LISTEN`

turns out that it listen on port **1401**

So I wrote that in the field of the server "**localhost, 1401**"
and it works,
There is another solution,

which is in the docker PREFERENCES and its about the memory you have to give it at least 3.25 GB so that the SQL Server runs.